# Using parameters from S3 object keys in AWS Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

My objects are structured as follows:

```
year=X/month=Y/day=Z/hour=I/minute=J/something.gz
```

Can I somehow contain these parameters in Athena query like:

```
... WHERE year=2022
```

or do I have do do `regexp_like` on a `$path`?

Comment: Did you tell athena that the table is partitioned by year, month, day, hour, minute? Does the backing glue table have paritions?

Comment: I did not tell it. Let me check these options

Answer (score 0):

As of @luk2302 comment - look for "partition" keyword